# How to display a showTimePicker after setting a date on showDatePicker in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to implement a reminder feature in my application which reminds the user to do a particular task at a selected time. I have implemented a `showDatePicker` widget to select the date and month but i am unsure on how to display a `showTimePicker` after a date is selected in the `showDatePicker`

Could i get a suggestion on how this can be implemented?

code which displays the `showDatePicker`:

```
  _selectDate() async {
    final DateTime picker =await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: DateTime.now(),
        firstDate: DateTime(2010),
        lastDate: DateTime(2040)
    );

    if (picker != null) {
      print(picker);
      _daysPageController.jumpToDay(picker);
//        Navigator.pop(context);

//        print(selectedDate);
//       await runJump(selectedDate);
//       return selectedDate;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very simple, it creates a single function that in sequence calls the methods showDatePicker() and showTimePicker().

```
Future _selectDayAndTime(BuildContext context) async {

   DateTime _selectedDay = await showDatePicker(
     context: context,
     initialDate: DateTime.now(),
     firstDate: DateTime(2018),
     lastDate: DateTime(2030),
     builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) => child
   );

   TimeOfDay _selectedTime = await showTimePicker(
     context: context,
     initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
   );


   if(_selectedDay != null && _selectedTime != null) {
     //a little check
   }
}
```